# Add TextBox strings as numbers

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a counter that updates when the calculate button is pressed, but when I press it it add it like:

```
11111
```

where the answer should be `5`.

```
    Const tax = 1.05

    Dim capPrice = 4.0
    Dim espPrice = 2.5
    Dim latPrice = 3.5
    Dim icedPrice = 3.0


    'keeping here teporarily

    Dim takeAway = True

    If (takeAway = True) Then

        capCounter.text = capCounter.text + capAmount.text
        espCounter.Text = espCounter.Text + espAmount.Text
        latCounter.Text = latCounter.Text + latAmount.Text
        icedCounter.Text = icedCounter.Text + icedAmount.Text
```

Comment: Text is a string property, whatever you type in the textbox is still a string not a number.

Comment: so I should remove the .text?

Comment: No, you take the text and convert it to a number (of the appropriate type, integer or floating point) do you math and then convert back the number to a string storing the result in the Text property again

Comment: Put `Option Strict On` at the top of your code _or_ set it in your project's properties.

Answer (score 3):

What you observe is string concatenation because a TextBox stores strings. You have to convert it to a number, for example with `Int32.Parse`, then you can sum the values:

```
Dim capCount As Int32
Dim capAmount as Int32
Dim validCapCount = Int32.TryParse(capCounter.Text, capCount)
Dim validCapAmount = Int32.TryParse(capAmount.Text, capAmount)
If validCapCount AndAlso validCapAmount Then
    capCounter.Text = (capCount + capAmount).ToString()
End If
' do the same with the other values ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Property `Text` of a control is a `String`.

If you want to perform your addition, you must convert those texts to a Integer first :

```
capCounter.text = (CType(capCounter.text, Integer) + CType(capAmount.text, Integer)).ToString()
```

(This if you are sure it will only be integers contained in the texts)

Answer (score 0):

If you will use it for numbers only and allow user imput I will recommend you to use a numericUpDown and not a textboxt.

Then you can use the `Value` property of the numericupdown and it will return a numeric value, not a String.

However, if you need it to be a textbox, use CType as SuperPeanut sugested or TryParse as Tim sugested

Answer (score 0):

Most of the other comments explain most of it, but have you tried using a different type of control to display the information, perhaps a NumericUpDownControl?